# Bluetooth (blueman-manager) not working on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

When I run `blueman-manager` in terminal, I get this error:

```
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting  
blueman-manager 12.42.28 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.  
blueman-manager 12.42.28 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It says that no adapter is found.

Comment: Check if any physical switch is there for Bluetooth, if yes turn on and re-check.

Comment: I found this in GRUB: " GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nommconf pcie_aspm=off" " also read delete this can solve it, but also harm. What do you think?

Comment: I have now Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and it is working well. Problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Per the error you have no adapter that Ubuntu can find. If there is a enable/disable switch try switching it and see if the adapter gets detected. If it was a driver issue it would show up, but not work correctly. Until an adapter is detected it will give the same message.

```
pcie_aspm=      [PCIE] Forcibly enable or disable PCIe Active State Power
                Management.
        off     Disable ASPM.
        force   Enable ASPM even on devices that claim not to support it.
                WARNING: Forcing ASPM on may cause system lockups.
```

Comment: I found this in GRUB: " GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nommconf pcie_aspm=off" " also read delete this can solve it, but also harm. What do you think?

Comment: first I would edit and not delete that line, quiet splash just makes the boot quiet and show the splash screen, where did you read this?

Comment: After looking into it, removing the pcie_aspm=off part may do the trick, leave all else as is, see my updated solution

Comment: I edited grub and delete only "pci=nommconf pcie_aspm=off" but still not working. I found here guy delete "pci=nomsi" which solved it: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249472

Comment: when I try" "sudo systemctl start dbus" terminal shows me:
"Failed to start dbus.service: Operation refused, unit dbus.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop)."